# Pygame-menu dice rolling GUI. Stuck on displaying returned integer values on screen?

Tags: python, pygame-menu

I recently wrote a command line program for random dice rolls for the various types of D&D dice, and I want to turn it into a basic GUI next.

I've got the below image worked out using Pygame-Menu library, and I also have functions which return a random dice roll for each button.

But how do I get the result of the dice rolls displayed on a surface on the screen?
I tried reading the library documentation but I didn't see anything on this topic that I understood.
I also tried to blit a text rect surface onto the screen but it didn't seem to work either.

Is anyone familiar with this particular Pygame library who can assist?

[image: Pygame-Menu "Dungeon Dice" GUI]

```
import random
import pygame
import pygame_menu

screen_width = 320
screen_height = 520

done = False
White = (255,255,255)
Grey = (179,179,179)
Black = (17,17,17)
Green = (30,215,96)


pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption('Dungeon Dice')
FPS = 60
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
width = screen.get_width()
height = screen.get_height()
rollsound = pygame.mixer.Sound("roll.mp3")
mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
font = pygame.font.SysFont('Calibri', 48)
screen.fill(Black)


def rolld20():
    d20output = random.randint(1,20)
    pygame.mixer.Sound.play(rollsound)
    return(d20output)

def rolld12():
    d12output = random.randint(1,12)
    pygame.mixer.Sound.play(rollsound)
    return(d12output)

def rolld10():
    d10output = random.randint(1,10)
    pygame.mixer.Sound.play(rollsound)
    return(d10output)

def rolld8():
    d8output = random.randint(1,8)
    pygame.mixer.Sound.play(rollsound)
    return(d8output)

def rolld6():
    d6output = random.randint(1,6)
    pygame.mixer.Sound.play(rollsound)
    return(d6output)

def rolld4():
    d4output = random.randint(1,4)
    pygame.mixer.Sound.play(rollsound)
    return(d4output)

def rolld100():
    d100output = random.randint(1,100)
    pygame.mixer.Sound.play(rollsound)
    return(d100output)

menu = pygame_menu.Menu('Dungeon Dice', screen_width, screen_height, theme=pygame_menu.themes.THEME_DEFAULT)

menu.add.button('D4', rolld4)
menu.add.button('D6', rolld6)
menu.add.button('D8', rolld8)
menu.add.button('D10', rolld10)
menu.add.button('D12', rolld12)
menu.add.button('D20', rolld20)
menu.add.button('D100', rolld100)
menu.add.button('Quit', pygame_menu.events.EXIT)

menu.mainloop(screen)
```

Comment: Show us the code you already have, including what didn't work.

Comment: Returning values from event functions doesn't actually do anything for you.  Return values are just ignored.  You have to call other functions or modify other data from within those event functions to accomplish anything.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `menu.mainloop()` it handles all the pygame events which limits your options.  Looking at the pygame_menu docs I created a main loop that allowed processing other pygame events.  I also took some liberties with your die setup and roll function.  This code will wait for the sound to complete before displaying the value.

```
import random
import pygame
import pygame_menu
import time

screen_width = 320
screen_height = 520

done = False
White = (255,255,255)
Grey = (179,179,179)
Black = (17,17,17)
Green = (30,215,96)


pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption('Dungeon Dice')
FPS = 60
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
width = screen.get_width()
height = screen.get_height()
rollsound = pygame.mixer.Sound("roll.mp3")
mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
font = pygame.font.SysFont('Calibri', 48)
screen.fill(Black)

SONG_END = pygame.USEREVENT + 1

def roll(faces):
    global value
    result_output.set_title(f'Rolling D{faces}...')
    value = random.randint(1,faces)
    channel = pygame.mixer.Sound.play(rollsound)
    channel.set_endevent(SONG_END)
    
def roll_done():
    global value
    result_output.set_title(str(value))
    
menu = pygame_menu.Menu('Dungeon Dice', screen_width, screen_height, theme=pygame_menu.themes.THEME_DEFAULT)

for die_size in [4,6,8,10,12,20,100]:
    menu.add.button(f'D{die_size}',lambda faces=die_size: roll(faces))   
    
menu.add.button('Quit', pygame_menu.events.EXIT)

result_output = menu.add.label('Result',label_id='result')

# menu.mainloop(screen)  # removed this
# new main loop follows:
while True:
    events = pygame.event.get()    
    for event in events:
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit()
        elif event.type == SONG_END:
            roll_done()
    if menu.is_enabled():
        menu.update(events)
        menu.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.update()
```